# Java which library I should use to receive and send sms via RS232 on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, com, sms, javax.comm

I want to write application to send sms via COM port. Currently I have Windows, but then this application should works on Linux too.
I found javax.comm library here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html 
but I don't know from where I can download jar file ? Then I found RXTX library but I don't if it is good ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [SMSJ](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/). It has several implementations. One is "local": it wraps RXTX library providing higher level well designed API. Others use well-known web services that send SMSs.

Comment: I try using this library, but doesn't work. I try to send sms via gsm modem, not gateway. When I run this line of code:SmsSender smsSender = SmsSender.getGsmSender("COM5"); I got error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.marre.sms.transport.gsm.SerialComm.<clinit>(SerialComm.java:58)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
I assume I have to add any library to loging

Comment: I added the comm.jar file to my project classpath

Answer (score 0):

i have used rxtx on a small project on windows. it worked fine. it also claims to work on linux.

Answer (score 0):

http://smslib.org/ is a relatively mature Java sms sending/receiving library that makes use of RxTx and SUN JavaComm.